# Contact Form 7 does not deliver attachments

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, contact-form

I have checked relevant existing questions and they are not the same as this.

Basically I am trying to use the file upload capability but the resulting email message is missing its attachments.

I have created a form with two file upload elements. After submission, the form say it was sent OK, and it arrives but the attachments are missing.

Short code tag:
    [contact-form-7 id="273" title="You have something to share?"]

Form definition:
     Your Name (required)
       [text* your-name]

```
<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> The title of the work
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Any comments you wish to make about the work
    [textarea your-message] </label>
<label> The work you wish to share - (max file size 2Mb) (in Open Document format (LibreOffice or OpenOffice Write (.odt), MS Word (.doc, .docx) or plain text(.txt)
[file* your-story limit:2mb filetypes:odt|doc|docx|txt|pdf id:fileupload] 
</label>

<label> (optional) A picture (.png, .jpg only) to illustrate your work (max file size 2Mb) (please respect copyright requirements)
[file your-image limit:2mb filetypes:jpg|jpeg|png id:imageupload]
</label>
[recaptcha]
[submit "Send"]
```

The form was generated using the form generator. Only the captions were edited by hand. I am not sure why one has [file... and the other [file*...

Any pointers greatly appreciated. I have searched but not found a similar problem out there.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my own stupidity. 
I created the form on the FORM tab of the contact form editor, but did not then go to the MAIL tab which defines the layout of the resulting email.
All the other fields are included in the mail template by default, but not file attachments. Once I added references to the two file upload elements all was fine.